# How to load parameter specific rows from same store in different grids EXTJS

Tags: extjs

i have a store consisting data of Name , DOB, jobType.

am creating grids based on Job type.. All the people with a particular job type are loaded in one grid.

problem is that ...inorder to load particular records am removing unessential records of different job types from the Store.. which is causing problem while loading the same store in different Grid (different job type)

Ex: i have total of 10 records.. 5 of which are Engineers, 3 are doctors and 2 are Teachers.

in order to display grid for Engineers am removing records of remaining job types..

after the First Grid.. am unable to load remaining Grids.. since the data is removed permanently

Comment: do u have different stores for each grid?  I'd recommend splitting up the grids to reference different stores if not.  If you only want to load the data from the service once, then you could do an `Ext.Ajax.request` and load data to all the stores in it's `success` `callback`

Comment: actually the Grids are auto generated... Suppose there is a new profession added in the Store like actor... a new grid will be created.. Can you suggest me how do i refer different stores for each grid...

Comment: Is there any chance of creating clones of actual Store.

Comment: I have been trying on grouping in sencha... But when i get a group it returns an array instead of Store.. How do i change it to a store.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chained](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.ChainedStore) stores:

> A chained store is a store that is a "view" of an existing store. The
>   data comes from the source, however this view of the store may be
>   sorted & filtered independently without having any impact on the
>   source store.

A working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/108a